# SVG with 10.000+ nodes - fast in IE and Safari, slow in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: performance, google-chrome, internet-explorer, svg

I'm facing a problem that I thought would have been easier to solve than it actually is.

I want to create a puzzle with 4860 pieces for a game. The mesh of the puzzle is made with SVG. Below I'm reporting part of the code, just to give you an idea. The code is working as you can see in the last link I gave you.

I created in defs a list of paths (18 in total), then a long list of 4860  so that I can make my puzzle.
When the mouse moves over one piece, I want this piece to be highlighted.
That's the code (first part), followed by a series of  tags like the one in the example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.4, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg version="1.1" width="1200" height="1200" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
      <defs>
          <style type="text/css">
            .use1 {
                stroke: #000000;
                fill: #ffffff;
                fill-opacity: 0.1;
                stroke-linecap: butt;
            }
            .use1:hover {
                fill: #ffffff;
                fill-opacity: 0.8;
                stroke: #3273BE;
                stroke-width: 10;
                }
            .base {
                     }

          </style>

      <path id="a0" d="m152.199493 121.414993c-0.349991 2.4 -0.3 4.8 0 7.169998c1.200012 8.3 6.6 15.9 16.3 17.419998c12.858994 2 14 -5.5 23.2 . (...) "/>
      .... the other 17 paths .....
</defs>
<image x="0" y="0" width="1200" height="720" xlink:href="lana-del-rey-ultraviolence-recensione.jpg" />

<use xlink:href="#C5" x="-50" y="-50" transform="scale(0.088) rotate(0)" class="use1" id="1"/>
....
... x 4860 ....
....
</svg>
```

You can see the result here:
http://www.ridiesorridi.it/puzzle/17.svg

If you open it in Safari or IE it works PERFECTLY with no lag. If you open in Chrome or Firefox to highlight a piece it's extremely slow. You can imagine when I put this SVG inside an HTML page ... !! Instead in IE and Safari it keeps working great.

My question is: how can I solve this problem with Chrome and Firefox?
I've already tried to remove extra decimals (to "optimize svg") but it didn't work.

**Edit**  I noticed that in Chrome and Firefox, if I zoom in (like 400%) it works PERFECTLY. Once it has all the elements together, it keeps having problems (compared to IE and Safari)

Answer (score 2):

Reducing accuracy would only help parsing speed.  Once the SVG was parsed, it shouldn't make a difference.

I am not sure what, if any, optimisations FF and Chrome use when testing hover for SVG elements.  But I would certainly try reducing the complexity of the pieces.  For instance, the piece "g1" has 89 path commands in its definition.  You should be able to reduce that by 4x, at least, and still get an accurate jigsaw piece shape.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm gonna try it now. I'll report the results of experiment.

Comment: I've tried, but still the same. I've reduced the svg, editing each single node manually. As you can see, in IE and Safari works perfect, in Chrome and Firefox not the same. I found out one thing: if in Chrome I zoom (400%) it works PERFECTLY like IE but, of course, I see just a little part of elements. Any other idea?

Comment: Try dividing the `<use>` elements into groups.  For example, one `<g>` per row.  That may allow the browser to eliminate whole rows at a time by testing against the group bbox first.

Comment: Paul, thanks again for your reply, but it's still the same. I've tried to put a g for  each row, then a g was half of a row, finally a g for each use (that's the version you can find in the link). Still the same in all 3 cases ... :(

Comment: A group for each use wouldn't help.  The idea was to create a hierarchy that the browser could use to quickly narrow done the piece you were over.

Comment: Perhaps it is just the sheer numbers then.  You should probably report your findings as a bug in FF and Chrome.

Comment: Yes, sorry, leaving the <g> for each piece was not the best, but as I wrote you, first I tried <g> for each row, but was everything the same. Anyway, thanks for your help. The best place where to report the bug for Chrome and FF according to your experience?

Comment: from FF got a link to this answer
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=934411
but honestly I didn't understand what I have to do practically ....

Comment: The info in that referred bug is internal implementation discussion by the FF devs.  There is nothing there that can help you right now.